# How to destroy a context properly in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a React [context](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context)

This context will provide a service, and this service will subscribe to some external events to stay updated. To prevent any leaks, I must therefore clean up this service by unsubscribing when the context will be destroyed.

Unlike `useEffect` to which we can return a callback when the component is destroyed, I do not know how to do the same with the context. How to do so, or what is the correct alternative ?

Note: my intuition is that I should create a service within a useEffect() and set that one it to the context, but it seems cumbersome for what looks like a simple dependency injection.

Comment: how do you do side effect while creating context? Can you show the related code?

Comment: Hi hackape, I'm using an observable to subscribe to the source emitter, I therefore have to unsubscribe at some point (when I won't need the service anymore). The garbage collector will not free anything as the subscription is still running. Also, a subscription keeps the subscribing object, meaning there is a relation A->B->A which can never be freed unless we explicitly unsubscribe. Ori's answer is exactly what I thought, but wasn't sure on how to do it properly. With his answer, I can now even build a generic ServiceProvider factory.

Comment: Yeah, `useEffect` is the way to go. Last I checked, React finally updated their doc, and they put it quite well: "`useEffect` is a React Hook that lets you [synchronize a component with an external system](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a context provider component, with your service encapsulated in a `useEffect` block. After you subscribe to the service pass, store a state with reference to the service/function/etc... that you want to context's consumers to use.

The `useEffect` has a cleanup function that you can use to unsubscribe when the component unmounts:

```
const ServiceContext = createContext();

const ServiceProvider = ({ initService, children }) => {
  const [service, setService] = useState(() => initService()); // you can initialize the service here

  useEffect(() => {
    // or initialize the service here if the process is async
    setService(serviceInstance);
    
    return () => {
      // cleanup unsubscribe from service
    };
  }, []);
       
  return (
    <ServiceContext.Provider value={service}>
      {children}
    </ServiceContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Not directly related to the question - I usually add a simple custom hook wrapper around `useContext`:

```
const useService = () => useContext(ServiceContext);
```

And then in your components:

```
const service = useService();
```

Another option is to create a Lazy service provider - the service is only initialized when `useService` is called:

```
const ServiceContext = createContext();

const ServiceProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const service = useRef(null); // store a reference to the service

  useEffect(() => () => {
      // cleanup unsubscribe from service
      // service.current?.unsubscribe() for example
  }, []);
  
  const getService = useCallback(() => {
    if(!service.current) service.current = initService // initialize if doesn't exist on ref
    
    return service.current
  }, []);
       
  return (
    <ServiceContext.Provider value={getService}>
      {children}
    </ServiceContext.Provider>
  );
}

const useService = () => {
  const getService = useContext(ServiceContext)
  
  return getService()
}
```

Comment: Hello, digging a little more, I realized we do not need any state. We can directly create the service within a ref and use the effect only to clear the service on destroy. I used your answer to create a serviceProviderFactory

Comment: The `serviceRef.current` is a bit dangerous because changing a ref doesn't cause a re-render, while changing the state does. This means that the value would be the initial ref value, unless something else causes a re-render of the provider. I would go with one of 2 options: state, or callback + ref. The callback checks if the ref have the service, and if not it initializes it. It then returns the service stored in the ref.

Comment: @FlavienVolken - see 2bd example - Lazy service provider

Comment: I don't think so, the service is supposed to be set only once and that's it, so in my understanding there should be no side effect using the ref. However, using the state, the service will be undefined during the first rendering, which is what I would like to avoid. Or I'm wrong ?

Comment: The service would be the initial value of the ref or state on first render, since `useEffect` happens after the render. Setting the state would cause another render, so the consumers would get the actual service, while setting the ref won't.

Comment: You are setting the ref using the `onCreate`. You usually set the ref with `useEffect` (after the render) or using a callback (like in the lazy example. The way you use `onCreate` might cause a problem - it's called on each render. It doesn't update the ref, but it will run all the service init code (subscribe to websockets for example) again and again.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I'm not using the ref property (to capture the component), I'm just using the ref hook only and directly initialized with the service value, in that way it's always defined. This is the purpose of `useRef(onCreate()); ` your lazy version is really nice too btw.

Comment: However, if the provider parent component re-renders, the provider would re-render as well calling `onCreate() `  again, etc.... In that case I would still use a state, because a state accepts lazy init function `useState(() => onCreate())` would only run `onCreate` once even if rendered multiple times. You can skip setting the state afterwards in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252265/discussion-between-flavien-volken-and-ori-drori).

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Ori Drori answer, I made a service provider factory

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export function serviceProviderFactory<T>(onCreate: () => T, onDestroy: (service: T) => void) {
  const ServiceContext = createContext<T | undefined>(undefined);

  const ServiceProvider = function ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    const serviceRef = useRef(undefined as T);
    serviceRef.current ??= onCreate();

    useEffect(() => {
      return () => {
        onDestroy(serviceRef.current);
      };
    }, []);

    return <ServiceContext.Provider value={serviceRef.current}>{children}</ServiceContext.Provider>;
  };

  const useServiceContext = () => {
    const serviceContext = useContext(ServiceContext);
    if (serviceContext === undefined)
      throw new Error(`No context found for constructor: ${onCreate.toString()}`);
    return serviceContext;
  };

  return [ServiceProvider, useServiceContext, ServiceContext] as const;
}
```

lazy loaded version [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDec1SoxIDCEAdsQB5ZwCuAzqSgDYsBG6A1to6RdVp8AogDNRSDLybJRcAL5xRUCCDgByQuhjqA3ACh9SKpFhK65DMApwmUAG7A0SAAorHAEyRQAYtugAngA8ACoAfAAUFCRaxABccBEAlHAAvGFwIdgUACJIDDAqAQkRdo7OCSEp6XD2EMAeKTj6cPgUBXAAyt7l-JTG8Kn4sX2CQRHJaRlVcAA+9OReosDkSB6RFksra0kGLW3kHd0OTq7uDd5p5pYw1uSJeGgAFsAsHoT38gmPL28fCchtAA6QEYAByEC8Cia+1aaHa8DKp1kVz4sgimyQy1WHjgKAYmV2hlacIRcAA5kgYMdeqimCRWBxuBNqhlmiSSUjnLIgWg6FAPvAAPxCobREbJAwc1qEGD8+5cpA8vkCpCUKUk+TYADaAF0ibD6EwxBIMCyprhDTKqfLEqzLdLOT1kVjefzBXAAGSeuC5fKFCABUrO7mulWComO+Qa1pauB6g0c2W2oI005kfo0IFuCCeS72Vh0JCpHCU6khpDyMI4Z6vd5q+RBAD0aecGcE2fOXigYQ10eJBw6fFbowGV0mNXZJPhh0RFfbY6GfAXNAiI5XMEjJOAcmDJzbAkXqSXiyx20aVrgMCeKgA7nBVvfhALoBEAAYQg6CJQQTY-qCDoUdAYNACQACQ4OKRBIECMAQJ0hQrOSyTyG+W7WnKUAKvOh6rlu-b7MmWHxiOOZ5lA0hIOuuG0NRmYwLqeIEjOBQGPI+hAA)

##### Example of usage:

Assuming you have this dummy service which needs to be destroyed at some point

```
import { serviceProviderFactory } from './service-context';

export class DummyService {
  public counter = 0;
  private handler;

  constructor() {
    this.handler = setInterval(() => this.counter++, 1000);
  }

  destroy() {
    clearInterval(this.handler);
  }
}
```

We can create the `useFunction` and `provider` using a one-liner.

`serviceProviderFactory` takes 2 arguments:

- a callback to create your service
- another one to destroy the service

```
export const [DummyServiceProvider, useDummyService] =
  serviceProviderFactory(
    () => new DummyService(),
    (service) => service.destroy()
  );
```

Then in your parent

```
    <DummyServiceProvider>
      <App />
    </DummyServiceProvider>
```

And to get the service from any child component

```
  console.log('service', useDummyService());
```

Comment: Your lazy service provider is great, but I think it doesn't work correctly with `Strict` mode on in React. As the component calling the `useContext` is rendered twise, the service is destroyed on first unmount, but the service initializer callback isn't called on second mount, so the service stays destroyed.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the strict mode would reuse the same component, would you suggest adding `serviceRef.current = undefined` right after calling the onDestroy callback ? This should ensure the service to be re-created, or do you have a better suggestion ?

Comment: I have actually tried that, and it doesn't help. The thing is cleanup effect that calls `onDestroy` is called when React destroys and re-creates the component, but the callback that creates the service is not called when re-creating, it's called only the first time (after which `onDestroy` effect is called). I'm not sure why that works that way, I'm not too deep on how `Strict` mode works, and why that happens. The only way I could fix that behavior, is [here](https://shorturl.at/ioptN) which I think is somewhat dirty way, which just ignores calling `onDestroy` effect first time.